# "Each and every" auf Deutsch ausdrücken – wie?

Tags: english-to-german

[dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/each+and+every.html) gibt einige Beispiele für die Übersetzung von “each and every” in Abhängigkeit vom Objekt, z. B. “each and every one of us” wird übersetzt als „jeder einzelne [sic] von uns“. Als Standardübersetzung wird „alle und jeder“ angegeben.

Schwierig wird das jedoch bei Ausdrücken wie “I've traveled each and every highway” (Bsp. aus dem Song *[My Way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aht9hcDFyVw&feature=related)*), die sich nicht auf Personen beziehen. Wie könnte man das auf Deutsch sagen und dabei den schönen Klang von “each and every” bewahren (und „ich reiste jede und alle Autobahn[en]“ vermeiden)?

Comment: Schlichtweg mit *über alle*?! *Und ich fuhr über alle Autobahnen* wobei du damit keinen schönen Klang mehr bewahrst, was aber eher an *Autobahnen* liegt.

Comment: Ich muss ein wenig an den Song *Thomas D - Rückenwind* denken, indem es heißt: *Wir betreten neue Wege, die wir noch nicht hatten.*

Comment: @Em1: *über alle*, vielleicht *Ich reiste über alle Straßen* ("Autobahn" ist wirklich sehr, sehr hässlich) funktioniert nicht schlecht. Es geht mir allerdings bei der Frage darum, wie *each and every* generell ausgedrückt werden könnte (es ist aber auch denkbar, dass es da nichts gibt und immer eine individuelle Lösung gesucht werden muss).

Comment: Ganz allgemein geht nimmer. Immer kontextbezogen. Aber die gängingen Übersetzungen wurden schon gesagt.

Comment: Bedenke, sowohl each als auch every bezeichen: *jede/jeder/jedes*. In Kombination betonst du nur um so mehr, dass es um *jegliche* geht. Je nach Kontext klingt dann die eine oder ander Übersetzung besser. Du kannst z.b. ja auch sagen: *Wir fuhren über jegliche Straßen* - *Wir befuhren jede Straße*. Klingt nur alles besch...eiden. Betrachte aber das Beispiel aus dem Song. Wenn du es geschickt anstellt, kannst du das auch als mögliche Übersetzung nehmen OHNE *each and every* wirklich zu übersetzen (auch wenn du vllt etwas den Kontext entfremdest).

Comment: Oder wie wärs hiermit: *Anyone who is not seriously concerned to clear up each and every one of these irregularities ...* -> *Wer nicht ernsthaft daran interessiert ist, diese Mißstände **ausnahmslos** aufzuklären, ...*

Comment: Übrigens entspricht leider die von [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/each+and+every.html) angegebene Übersetzung „jeder einzelne von uns“ noch der alten Rechtschreibung. In der aktuellen Rechtschreibung schreibt man gemäß § 57(1): „jeder Einzelne von uns“.

Comment: Warum der Downvote? Macht mir nicht viel aus, finde die Gründe aber interessant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Zur Übersetzung eines Wortes ist stets der Kontext entscheidend. Im Falle von *each and every* ist es zwar schon eher eine Redensart (keine Redewendung) und Redensarten haben in der Regel eine feststehende Bedeutung (z. B. *Schwein haben = Glück haben = [to have a stroke of luck](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+stroke+of+luck) or just [to luck out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/luck+out)*), dennoch kann man *each and every* nicht mit einer Phrase, einem Wort oder einer deutschen Redensart generalisieren.

Es gibt jedoch eine Handvoll deutscher Wörter und Redensarten, die oft zutreffen. Dafür muss man sich aber erstmal der Bedeutung von *each and every* klar werden.

> Also, [every last one](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/every+last+one); every single one. Every individual in a group, as in Each and every student must register by tomorrow, or I've graded every last one of the exams, or Every single one of his answers was wrong. All of these phrases are generally used for emphasis. The first, although seemingly redundant, has replaced all and every, first recorded in 1502. The first variant dates from the late 1800s, and both it and the second are widely used. Also see every tom, dick, and harry. Every mother's son (late 1500s) and every man Jack (mid-1800s) are earlier versions that refer only to males. <sup>[YOURDICTIONARY](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/each-and-every-one)</sup>

Und wie ich schon in den Kommentaren angedeutet habe, haben *each* und *every* nahezu eine identische Bedeutung. Am Rande bemerkt: Interessant in dem Zusammenhang sind [diese Frage](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6656/16833) und [diese Frage](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/33834/16833).

> [each](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/each?q=each): used to refer to every one of two or more people or things, regarded and identified separately
>
> [every](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/every?q=every): used before a singular noun to refer to all the individual members of a set without exception

Durch die Verbindung der beiden Wörter wird eine Art *Steigerung* erzielt (obwohl mehr als alle ja eh nicht mehr geht) bzw. es wird betont, dass *wirklich jede(r)* gemeint ist.

Und basierend darauf kann man jetzt eine Liste mit deutschen Wörtern und Redensarten erstellen, die man dafür verwenden kann:

- **alle/alles**
- alle miteinander/allesamt
- **sämtliche**
- **jede/jeder/jedes**
- jedermann/jedefrau
- jedwede/jedweder/jedwedes
- jegliche/jeglicher/jegliches
- **ausnahmslos**
- ohne Ausnahme
- Jung und Alt
- Arm und Reich
- und so weiter und so fort

<sup>(Die fettgedruckten Wörter sind meine persönlichen Favoriten.)</sup>

Also in deinem Beispiel *I've traveled each and every highway* (wobei ich travel keinesfalls mit *reisen* übersetzen würde, weil man schlicht und ergreifend keine Straßen bereist) gibt es beispielsweise folgende Möglichkeiten (highway übersetze ich mit *Wege* weil es einfacher schöner klingt):

> Ich bin auf allen Wegen gefahren.
>
> Ich habe jegliche Wege genommen.
>
> Ich habe sämtliche Wege befahren.

Und in einem zusammenhängenden Text könnte es sogar eleganter sein, den Satz zu negieren:

> Es gab keine Straße, die wir nicht befahren haben.

Comment: Wunderbar ausführliche und treffende Erörterung. Auch wenn es eine andere stärker bevotete Antwort gibt, bekommt diese den Zuschlag. Besten Dank an alle.

Answer (score 10):

Generell würde ich es schlicht mit "jede" oder "jede einzelne" übersetzen.

"Ich bereiste jede einzelne Straße."

Wenn es nur mit "jede" übersetzt wird, ist der Effekt weniger stark (vergleiche "each" und "each and every").

Comment: Nur um es anzumerken: Literally best translation, aber äußerst bescheidenes Deutsch.

Comment: +1, mir gefällt der dem Original ähnliche Rhythmus. Was bescheidenes (oder sogar *äußerst* bescheidenes) Deutsch ist, ist meiner Meinung nach Ansichtssache.

Comment: @Jan Mir geht es darum, dass man Straßen nicht *bereist*, es sei denn zu schlägst dein Zelt in der Oxford Street auf. Wobei ich inzw. sogar weiß, dass *[to travel](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/travel)* mehr Bedeutungen hat, als nur reisen. Und damit nehme ich übrigens meine Statement *Literally best translation* amtlich zurück. ;p

Comment: @Em1: ach guck - ich hab mich jetzt wirklich nur auf das "jede einzelne" bezogen und mich schon gefragt, was daran schlechtes Deutsch sein sollte ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Im Deutschen gibt es mit `Alles und Jedes` (Alle und Jede, Alle und Jeden) ein ähnliches Konstrukt.

Aber wieso kann man es hier nicht verwenden? Es liegt daran, dass das eine sich auf die Einzahl, das andere auf die Mehrzahl bezieht, wodurch eine sprachliche Zusammenziehung misslingt:

- Alle und jede Straße: alle Straße geht nicht.
- Alle und jede Straßen: jede Straßen geht nicht.
- Alle Straßen und jede Straße: Geht, aber die Wiederholung klingt nicht gut.

Man kann wohl `wir besuchten Santa Fe und sahen alles und jedes` - ich bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob es dann nicht Substantivierungen sind: `und sahen Alles und Jedes`.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "alle Wege, jede Straße"? So etwas würde ich aber nur in einem Liedtext oder Gedicht benutzen, überall sonst reicht mir ein einfaches "alle" ganz gut. Man muss ja auch nicht alle und jede Wendung aus dem Englischen übersetzen :3

Comment: `wir probierten alle Kuchen, jede Torte` - wenn man das gleiche oder ähnliche wiederholt kommt das dem nahe, aber funktioniert auch mit `jeden Kuchen, jede Torte` oder eben `alle Wege, alle Straßen`/ `jeden Weg und jede Straße`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't translate a song that way. You can't insist on duplication of every idomatic expression on a word-by-word basis. But in this case, it's odd that we have a Yiddish expression for the *complete* phrase "each and every highway": we say "jeder weg un steg", and the expression is used in the exact same sense as that conveyed in the original song.

Although it's not relevant to the question, I actually translated this same song into Yiddish. My first two lines were:

> Mein zeit is schõn varbei; dâs Richter wart auf mir in Himmel.
>
> Un jetzt mus ich varlâsen ot der Welt vun Staub un Schimmel.

It’s a lot more important to fit the syllables to the melody than to duplicate the exact word pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to translate the following lines of the Sinatra-song:

> I've travelled each and every highway
>
> and more, much more than this
>
> I did it my way

into German:

> Ich befuhr sämtliche Straßen
>
> und mehr, viel mehr als das
>
> Ich tat's auf meine Art

I didn't find a way to keep the beautifil alliteration, though :-(